# SQLite querying on datetime not returning any results, or returns all results

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I have been researching this topic for 2 days on what I thought would be a simple question, but have not been able to yield any results that return what I am looking for.

I currently have a database with the following schema, that I am trying to query to pull results from a certain time period.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE tbLogger(time INT, temp REAL, fanOn INT);
```

A sample of the return from a select * displays the following:

```
2022-05-26 03:51:53.832585-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:52:57.410400-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:54:04.549302-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:55:08.179198-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:56:11.808473-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:57:15.447874-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:58:22.605812-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-26 03:59:26.219187-04:00  78.8        1
```

If I am understanding correctly, I am storing the data in epoch time format, which I beleive is confirmed by the way that I am inserting the new data in from the logging program (Python):

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_filename) as conn:
                conn.execute("insert into tbLogger values(?,?,?)",
                (datetime.datetime.now(tz = timezone), temp_f, fanOn))
```

When I try to query against a specific time that I know exists, the query returns no results

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbLogger WHERE time = datetime(1653465566, 'unixepoch');
sqlite>
```

However if I query with BETWEEN two time periods, then all results in the database are returned:

```
SELECT * FROM tbLogger WHERE time BETWEEN datetime(1653364800, 'unixepoch') AND datetime(1653451140, 'unixepoch');
2022-05-25 09:46:54.551584-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-25 09:47:58.275281-04:00  78.8        1         
2022-05-25 09:49:08.986005-04:00  78.8        1  
..... continued
```

This is leading me to believe that when I am querying, I am meeting the criteria of "between" with the conversion to datetime in the WHERE statement. I for the life of me, cannot figure out what values I am actually needing to place in the WHERE statement to get the information I am looking for. I am hoping that this is a simple error and I am missing something so easy that I am flying over it.

Essentially, I am looking for a way to query between two dates (regardless of the times) and return all of those results from the db, to pull into my plotter.

If there is an easier way to store the data into the database, it will be very simple for me to start fresh, so no problems if that is the preferred solution. In my reading of many stack posts, INT seemed to be the best to store times in SQLite, so I hope at least that part was right!

Thank you in advance for the help.

So it would seem that despite the fact that I am storing the data as `INT`, the data is being stored as a `STRING`. When I query:
`SELECT * FROM tbLogger WHERE time LIKE '2022-05-25 22:%';`

I am returned the results that I am looking for:

```
2022-05-25 22:00:27.495144-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:01:31.201165-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:02:34.906498-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:03:38.582368-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:04:45.744486-04:00|80.6|1
```

I guess this answers my ultimate question of how I can query, as I now can have fields on the server for both time and date and use the like statement, but that does not solve why the `INT` is being stored like a `STRING`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a record that was returned that you didn't expect? Your timestamps run from May 25 4:00am to May 26 3:59am, so the data that is being returned in your example *does* indeed all fall within the period you queried?

Comment: The table definition says that `time` is `INT`, not `DATETIME`. Why is `SELECT *` showing it as a date and time?

Comment: Please update your question, so that the example data there reflects the actual problem you're having - don't share additional code, data or output in the comments.

Comment: @Grismar, thanks, new to the question asking here. Updated the code to show a query for returning dates on 2022-05-24.

Comment: When you query for a specific datetime it has to match that datetime exactly.  Are you sure you have a time matching, `1653465566` (appears to be '2022-05-25T16:59:26' , where your sample contains microseconds, which wouldn't match)?  It could help if the sample output is in unix timestamp format.

Comment: `datetime()` returns strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, which will never be equal to the strings you're storing.

Comment: It's still not clear from the data samples and outputs you provide whether there even is a real problem - you query for exactly `1653465566`, which is 'May 25, 2022 7:59:26 AM', however it's not clear that your data contains a record for exactly that point in time (down to the second, no fractions allowed) and it appears your data contains a higher resolution timestamp, including decimals for fractions of seconds. If you want those, simply select between 1653465566 and 1653465567, which will be one second apart, covering that interval. (or from 1653465565, to cover the previous second)

Comment: This is where I get confused. Because when I use the `BETWEEN` with any criteria, it always returns all lines in the database. Am I better off storing the data in 2 columns, one with date, and other with time down to the second? I do not care/need splits beyond seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Added to main post as well:

So it would seem that despite the fact that I am storing the data as `INT`, the data is being stored as a `STRING`. When I query: `SELECT * FROM tbLogger WHERE time LIKE '2022-05-25 22:%';`

I am returned the results that I am looking for:

```
2022-05-25 22:00:27.495144-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:01:31.201165-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:02:34.906498-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:03:38.582368-04:00|80.6|1
2022-05-25 22:04:45.744486-04:00|80.6|1
```

I guess this answers my ultimate question of how I can query, as I now can have fields on the server for both time and date and use the like statement, but that does not solve why the INT is being stored like a STRING.